# Lucene Index files getting Corrupted

Tags: java, websphere-7

Could the lucene files get corrupted because there was a network connectivity issue?

In our application we have quartz job which runs to index the records. This job runs every minute. Could there be issues with some index files, with some getting updated properly whereas some don't get updated at all. In such a case the search breaks with an exception about a file not found.

In addition to the above question if someone can let me know the main reasons when & why the index files could get corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'eve had issues in the past with our hardrives. The amount of data added to lucene was overloading the actual capacity of the hard drive to write things down.

When restarting the application, we'd have CorruptedIndexException and everything was screwed.

Comment: Thank you P. Lalonde... Looking for more thoughts on this